# The sum of the $n^{\text{th}}$ derivatives of a function

Tags: calculus

Does a function $g(x)$ exist where it is the sum of the $n^{\text{th}}$ derivatives of $f(x)$?

$$ \sum_n f^{(n)}(x) \stackrel{?}{=} g(x) $$

---

I was looking for a closed form of the series below:
$$\frac in \color{blue}{x^{2m}}+\frac{i^2}{n^2}\color{blue}{(2m)x^{2m-1}}+\frac{i^3}{n^3}\color{blue}{(2m)(2m-1)x^{2m-2}}+\cdots$$
Those in $\color{blue}{\text{blue}}$ look like the $n^\text{th}$ derivatives of $x^{2m}$. So I was wondering/asking if there is a closed form, or for any help if I am approaching the problem in a wrong direction.

Comment: The question seems to be incomplete or it is simply trivial.

Answer (score 0):

If the sum runs from $0$ to $\infty$ then $g(x)$ is identical to $f(x)$, given that $x$ is in the radius of convergence, i.e. Taylor expansion converges to the function itself.

If the sum is over some finite subset of natural numbers (including $0$) then the function $g(x)$ exists when all derivatives exist.

Comment: Is the first sentence true?